# PHP count from Database

Tags: sql, group-by

I have one php page which must show "Total Score" of "COUNTRY" for example

Let's say we have the following...

- user ABC with SCORE 20 from SUA
- user DEF with SCORE 7 from CANADA
- user GHI with SCORE 10 from SUA

Now what i want is to show total SCORE of SUA for example, which will be 30

```
SELECT score,country,COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE country GROUP BY score
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what is the question? you want to use the result of this query in your code?

Comment: Is just an example wich i found on internet. What i need is to edit that with correct informations

Comment: SELECT score,country,COUNT(*), SUM(score) as 'TOTALSCORE' FROM users WHERE country GROUP BY score

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [sum](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_sum.asp) function.

```
select sum(score) as 'total', country
from users
group by country
```

This will return something like:

```
+-------+---------+
| total | country |
+-------+---------+
|    30 | SUA     |
|     7 | Canada  |
+-------+---------+
```

And you can also filter out your query by country with the where clause:

```
select sum(score) as 'total', country
from users
where country = 'Canada'
```

Which would give the following:

```
+-------+---------+
| total | country |
+-------+---------+
|     7 | Canada  |
+-------+---------+
```

Comment: finaly. Thank you so much man. It works .I will aprove answer in 4 minutes

Comment: @DavidClaudiu No problem. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 3):

After you pull your data, create individual objects or nodes with each score, then just loop through them to add up the scores with "SUA"

Comment: while this is a valid answer, it is usually better to sum the data while doing the query because dbms are usually a lot faster than php

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this if you have score as integer/float/double:

```
SELECT SUM(score) as total, country from users GROUP BY score;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is best solved in your SQL before it gets to your PHP.

```
SELECT country, SUM(score) AS sumscore FROM users GROUP BY country
```

The you just enumerate it out like any other SQL query.